# Book Recommendation about radio frequency antennas and satellites

Tags: resource-recommendations, antennas, satellites, radio-frequency, radio

I have recently obtained a job in the field of radio frequency antennas and satellites, and I am interested in delving deeper into the subject. Could you recommend any books that cover these topics and are easily understandable, similar to the book **Physics: Principles with Applications by Douglas C. Giancoli**? It would be preferable if there is one comprehensive book that addresses all aspects, but if not, recommendations for books on these specific topics would also be appreciated.

Comment: The ARRL Antenna Handbook might be interesting.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Jon Custer: *The ARRL Antenna Handbook* is a useful compendium of practical applications of antenna theory, told from an engineering (algebra) rather than a physics (calculus) standpoint. It contains just enough theory to motivate the derivations that are used to develop real-life designs, and furnishes lots of examples. It spans the frequency range from kilohertz to gigahertz with special emphasis on those frequency bands that are set aside for the amateur radio hobby.

Note that it does *not* start with Maxwell's equations, so if you want that fundamental a level of exposition, you'd best look elsewhere in the physics literature instead.

The purchase of the book entitles you to a broad range of specialized downloads that go into greater detail than the book can cover.

An updated edition of this book comes out every year. The most recent updates include a wealth of information on mathematical modeling software for antenna design, which is the wave of the future in this field.

Answer (score 0):

There is good book of the coarse "Microwave engineering and antennas", from the following website: https://coursera.org/learn/microwave-antenna. The book: "Modern Antennas and Microwave Circuits" by Prof. dr.ir. A.B. Smolders, Prof.dr.ir. H.J. Visser and dr. Ulf Johannsen. Different antennas are studied such as horn, dipôle, magnetic dipôle etc. The discussion starts from the Maxwell equation, from a physical point of view. So it is useful to understand the functionality of the antennas.

There is a chapter on general antenna parameters in :
"Microwave and RF Design of Wireless Systems" by David M. Pozar. Which might be useful to understand system parameters.